# How to correctly implement browser caching for pagespeed insights?

Tags: php, http, caching, http-headers, seo

I am trying to optimize my landingspage for SEO purposes. The Google pagespeed tool might help so I am trying to get 100/100 but can't get past the browsercaching issue.

I tried adding caching by adding the following line in my header.php:

```
<?PHP 
header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000"); //30days (60sec * 60min * 24hours * 30days)
?>
```

But the tool still says I don't have any browsercaching.

I found another post here on SO that said you only have to add a meta tag like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

But I also still get the message from Pagespeed insights when using that line.

So what do I need?

Comment: have you checked that you have not turned OFF caching in your browser?

Comment: @RiggsFolly But it is Google that checks my page so even if I have it off then that still wouldn't matter right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to config your webserver to enable browser-side caching (sounds ironic yes)?

**Nginx** (add to your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

```
location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|jpeg|jpg|webp|png|svg|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf|ogg)$ {
  expires max; 
}
```

If you **don't** have access to your **nginx.conf**, ask your hosting provider or see if your server-side caching app has this option. If you do this yourself, you need to restart nginx afterward.

Source: https://www.wpfastestcache.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-leverage-browser-caching-on-nginx/

**Apache** (add to .htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On

  # Images
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/webp "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"

  # Video
  ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mpeg "access plus 1 year"

  # CSS, JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"

  # Others
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Source: https://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html

Good luck with your 100 score!